# Put Script Manager in master page

Tags: asp.net, coding-style, master-pages, scriptmanager

is it right to put script manager in master page ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't wrong, as such.

Really depends on your requirements.

If you need to use scripts in several pages that use the same master page, use [`ScriptManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398864.aspx) in the master page.

Just keep in mind that you can only have *one* `ScriptManager` in the whole loaded page, so you can't add one in content pages as well.

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398864.aspx) article on MSDN for an example (Using the ASP.NET UpdatePanel Control with Master Pages).

Comment: As a side-note, you can have ScriptManagerProxy on the content page which can have page specific scripts and services which are not needed by all pages and not included in Master Page ScriptManager.